# Can not assign to value: ‘downloadURL’ is a let constant

Tags: swift

I’m having problems with `downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL`. Does `let` have to be in front in order for it to work? When I do it says

> definition conflicts with previous value and value of type ‘StorageMetaData’ has no member ‘downloadURL’

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I have found nothing on it so far.

```
// You can also access to download URL after upload.
storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
    guard let downloadURL = url else {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        return
    }

    // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content type, and download URL
    downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to help you, we need some more information. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can answer your question.

Comment: There are way too many variables and properties named `downloadURL`. This is really confusing. Why do you create `downloadURL from `url` and then try to reassign or create a new `downloadURL` from `metadata.downloadURL`?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler tells you what is wrong. You use a `guard let` to create a let constant `downloadURL`. Once that constant has a value, it can't be changed. Then you try to change its value. That's not allowed.

Your code is confusing, because you first assign `downloadURL` with a guard let, and then you try to assign a completely different value to `downloadURL`. (In the 2nd case, you use `metadata.downloadURL`.

Why assign a value to `downloadURL` and then immediately forget that value and replace it with a different value?

Instead, you might write code like this:

```
storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
    //Use the name `inputURL` to indicate this is the URL passed to the closure
    guard let inputURL = url else {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        return
    }

    // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content type, and download URL
    let downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why not `guard url != nil else {` ? It doesn't seem like the OP is making any use of the result. And don't you need `let` in front of `downloadURL = ...` ?

Comment: Yes, I missed the `let`. As to the point of the guard let, it's hard to know the OPs intent. I gave him the benefit of the doubt that he actually needed that value in a local variable, but who knows.

Comment: He could also use guard let _ = ... if he doesn't need the value.